# stitching together ind images into pano results in bad aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-lightroom, panorama

I took some pano shots with my DJI Mini 2 drone but rather the a single image I got 26x distinct images. Consequently, I thought I might try to stich them together with Adobe Lightroom. I import the images and then go to Photo -> Photo Merge -> Panorama Merge but when I export the results I get a 9594x3368 image. According to https://facebook360.fb.com/editing-360-photos-injecting-metadata/  pano images need to have an aspect ration of 2:1 and my DJI Mini 2 stitched pano's aspect ratio is closer to 2.8:1.

I can crop the stitched pano's but if I do that the image is likely going to be all messed up when viewing it in a 360 image viewer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you since you haven't shared the image, but  the following method might be worth a try:

If you have access to Photoshop, it's possible to use [Content Aware Scaling](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/content-aware-scaling.html) to change the aspect ratio of an image without actually cropping it, or squishing the subject/s too much. For those without Photoshop, it's also possible in GIMP with the Liquid Rescale plugin.

In the layers panel, unlock the background layer for editing, then do *Edit > Content-Aware scale*. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag the centre handle at one edge. Finally, select, and crop the image to the selection to remove any leftover space.

Since you need a specific aspect ratio, it might be a good idea to set up a guide so you know how far to scale.

Obviously some distortion is unavoidable, but content aware scaling can help make it less obvious by protecting certain areas of an image from distortion as you scale. Also note that you can scale horizontally or vertically with this tool, and it would be entirely feasible to use a bit of either to achieve your desired result.

A quick example:

[image]

Note: if the result isn't as good as you expect, it's possible to manually select the areas you don't wish to distort. The process is explained in detail at the link posted above. It involves making a selection and saving it as an alpha channel.